# testing question

Tags: unit-test

writing test for aura apex controller and one of the methods being tested is just returning a list of contacts from a SOQL query my test is

```
 @isTest
  public static void getContactsTest() {
    List<Contact> c = ContactController.getContacts();
    System.assertEquals(c.size(), 3);
  }
```

and it works as I have a test setup creating the list of contacts i just wanted to know if i needed the other best practice tests like negative test or if this one positive test is all i should have

Comment: What would the negative test be?

Comment: dont know just remember testing best practices and wanted to know basically when other test should be made or not like in this case i cant think of any other test

Comment: assert first argument is always the expected result, second argument is actual result. You have coded yours backwards